# The top search box disappears when I hover over it

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress template that works fine but when I made it compatible with Arabic language I had this problem.

You can watch this GIF to better understand what exactly is the problem.

[image]

This is the code for the top search box:

```
    /* Top Search */
    var searchOpenBO = true;
    var theme_top_search_container = $( '.top-search' );

    // Top Search Button
    $( '.top-search-button' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( '#site-menu' ).slicknav( 'close' );
        if ( searchOpenBO ) {
            searchOpenBO = false;
            theme_top_search_container.css( 'display', 'none' );
        } else {
            searchOpenBO = true;
            theme_top_search_container.css( 'display', 'block' );
        }
    } );

    /* Menu Button */
    $( '.mobile-menu-button' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( '#site-menu' ).slicknav( 'toggle' );
        searchOpenBO = false;
        theme_top_search_container.css( 'display', 'none' );
    } );
    /* */

    /* Body Mouse Move */
    $( 'body' ).on( 'mousemove', function( event ) {
        if ( searchOpenBO && theme_top_search_container.width() ) {
            if ( event.pageX >= $( '.top-search-button' ).offset().left + 40 || event.pageY >= $( '.top-search-button' ).offset().top + 40 || event.pageY < $( '.top-search-button' ).offset().top - 40 ) {
                theme_top_search_container.css( 'display', 'none' );
                searchOpenBO = false;
            }
        } else {
            theme_top_search_container.css( 'display', 'none' );
            searchOpenBO = false;
        }
    } );
    /* */
```

```
<div class="top-extra-outer">
    <div class="top-extra">    
        <div class="top-extra-inner clearfix">
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'theme_show_header_social', 1 ) ) { echo baxel_insert_social_icons( 'header-social' ); } ?>
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'theme_show_header_search', 1 ) ) { ?>
                <div class="top-search-button fading"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                <div class="top-search"><input class="top-search-input" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( theme_translation( '_Keyword' ) ); ?>" name="s" id="s_top" /></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You show us only the CSS, the problem is probably in your JS, please post all relevant JS/HTML code to help us help you.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which should help you create a snippet which we can run.